# Как закрыть сокет без прямого доступа к нему?

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp

Я создал tcp соединение и не закрыл его, из-за этого я не могу теперь создать то же самое соединение, так как оно уже занято.
[image: Exception]

В этом примере я занял вот этот порт и адресс 0.0.0.0:50001
Могу я как-то вручную закрыть его на ubuntu, но при этом не перезагружать компьютер?

Answer (score 1):

Я немного почитал, и понял что у меня не завершился процесс, который занял этот ip:port.
Нужно просто найти какой процесс занял порт и убить его.
Сделать это в линуксе можно с помощью net-tools
[image]

И убить через монитор ресурсов

[image]

Comment: Для убийства есть еще `kill <id>` или `killall <name>`.